# How to use Glide js in Next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

How can I use script tag in next javascript in _app.js component and I want to use Glide javascript carousel in next javascript. I am unable use the script tag. so please help me as provide my code.

```html
import "../styles/globals.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
// import Script from "next/script";
import { Container, Row } from "react-bootstrap";
// import Head from "next/head";
import Contact from "./components/contact";



import Header from "./components/header";
import Footer from "./components/footer";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {/* <Head>
        <Script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@glidejs/glide" />
        <Script src="node_modules/@glidejs/glide/dist/glide.min.js"></Script>

    
      </Head>
      <link
        rel="stylesheet"
        href="node_modules/@glidejs/glide/dist/css/glide.core.min.css"
      ></link>
      <link
        rel="stylesheet"
        href="node_modules/@glidejs/glide/dist/css/glide.theme.min.css"
      ></link> */}
      <Header />
      <Component {...pageProps} />
      <div>
        <div>
          <Container>
            <Row>
              <Contact />
           
            </Row>
          </Container>
        </div>
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

Comment: Have similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73366892/why-glide-js-is-not-compatible-with-next-js-what-can-i-do

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is simple answer in these situations. As long as you use the frameworks like **next.js** or **CRA** you should use **NPM** packages instead of importing from cdn.

So, in this context:

```
npm install @glidejs/glide
```

and using ES Modules:

```
import Glide, { Controls, Breakpoints } from '@glidejs/glide/dist/glide.modular.esm'

new Glide('.glide').mount({ Controls, Breakpoints })
```

and for importing style you can use as following:

```
// Required Core Stylesheet
@import "node_modules/@glidejs/glide/src/assets/sass/glide.core";

// Optional Theme Stylesheet
@import "node_modules/@glidejs/glide/src/assets/sass/glide.theme";
```

As a side note, you **must** import global styles only in **_app.js** when you're using **next.js**