# Using Glide JS with Next.js: document is not defined

Tags: node.js, next.js, glidejs

I've created a plain HTML webiste with a carousel using Glide JS. Then I moved to Next JS and I'm stucked with a "ReferenceError: document is not defined" related to the script I use to run the carousel. I am aware about Node not having DOM, but still I don't know what to do to fix this.

The error here:

```
Server Error
ReferenceError: document is not defined

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Source
components/Glide.js (3:14) @ document

  1 | import Glide from '@glidejs/glide'
  2 | 
> 3 | let sliders = document.querySelectorAll('.glide');
    |          ^
  4 | for (let i = 0; i < sliders.length; i++) {
  5 |     let glide = new Glide(sliders[i], {
  6 |         startAt: 0,
```

This is my code:

components/Glide.js

```
import Glide from '@glidejs/glide'

let sliders = document.querySelectorAll('.glide');
    for (let i = 0; i < sliders.length; i++) {
        let glide = new Glide(sliders[i], {
            startAt: 0,
            autoplay: 2800,
            hoverpause: true,
        });
        glide.mount();
    }
```

pages/index.js (relevant part)

```
import Glide from "./components/Glide"

export default function Home() {
    return(
        <>
<div className="glide-container">
    <div className="glide">
        <div data-glide-el="controls" >
            <button data-glide-dir="<" className="glide__arrow glide__arrow--left">`{'<'}`</button>
            <button data-glide-dir=">" className="glide__arrow glide__arrow--right">`{'>'}`</button>
        </div>
        <div className="glide__track" data-glide-el="track">
            <ul className="glide__slides">

                <li className="glide__slide"><img src="1.jpg" />1</li>
                <li className="glide__slide"><img src="2.png" />2</li>
                <li className="glide__slide"><img src="3.png" />3</li>
                <li className="glide__slide"><img src="4.png" />4</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div className="glide__bullets" data-glide-el="controls[nav]">
            
            <button className="glide__bullet" data-glide-dir="=0"></button>
            <button className="glide__bullet" data-glide-dir="=1"></button>
            <button className="glide__bullet" data-glide-dir="=2"></button>
            <button className="glide__bullet" data-glide-dir="=3"></button>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

 
        </>
  )
}
```

To reproduce the error:

1. Create a new nextJS project by running  `npx create-next-app@latest` and using this configuration:

- What is your project named? my-app
- Would you like to use TypeScript? No
- Would you like to use ESLint? Yes
- Would you like to use Tailwind CSS? No
- Would you like to use `src/` directory? No
- Would you like to use App Router? (recommended) No
- Would you like to customize the default import alias? No
- What import alias would you like configured? @/*

2. Install GlideJS by running `npm install @glidejs/glide`
3. Create the two files described above.
4. run `npm run dev`

I tried looking at here:
[How to use Glide js in Next js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72212013/how-to-use-glide-js-in-next-js)

And here:
[Next.js: document is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60629258/next-js-document-is-not-defined)

But still, I can't figure out what I should do.

Comment: Share the full error from Next.js, and how to reproduce the error. Add it to the question

Comment: @RobinThomas I did it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did and worked:

1. Deleted Glide.js component (see question description)
2. Replaced the original glide-container div and everything inside at pages/index.js (relevant part) (see question description) with a `<GlideContainer />` tag
3. Created GlideContainer.js component as you can see below:

```
import React, { useLayoutEffect } from "react";
import Glide from '@glidejs/glide';

export default function GlideContainer() {
    useLayoutEffect(() => {
       let sliders = document.querySelectorAll('.glide');
    for (let i = 0; i < sliders.length; i++) {
        let glide = new Glide(sliders[i], {
            startAt: 0,
            autoplay: 2800,
            hoverpause: true,
        });
        glide.mount();
    }

    })

    return(
        <>
            <div className="glide-container">
                <div className="glide">
                    <div data-glide-el="controls" >
                        <button data-glide-dir="<" className="glide__arrow glide__arrow--left">{'<'}</button>
                        <button data-glide-dir=">" className="glide__arrow glide__arrow--right">{'>'}</button>
                    </div>
                    <div className="glide__track" data-glide-el="track">
                        <ul className="glide__slides">

                            <li className="glide__slide"><img src="img/PastEvents/9.jpg" /></li>
                            <li className="glide__slide"><img src="img/PastEvents/10.jpg" /></li>
                            <li className="glide__slide"><img src="img/PastEvents/11.jpg" /></li>
                            <li className="glide__slide"><img src="img/PastEvents/12.jpg" /></li>
                            <li className="glide__slide"><img src="img/PastEvents/13.jpg" /></li>
                            <li className="glide__slide"><img src="img/PastEvents/14.jpg" /></li>
                            <li className="glide__slide"><img src="img/PastEvents/15.jpg" /></li>
                            
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div className="glide__bullets" data-glide-el="controls[nav]">
                        
                        <button className="glide__bullet" data-glide-dir="=0"></button>
                        <button className="glide__bullet" data-glide-dir="=1"></button>
                        <button className="glide__bullet" data-glide-dir="=2"></button>
                        <button className="glide__bullet" data-glide-dir="=3"></button>
                        <button className="glide__bullet" data-glide-dir="=4"></button>
                        <button className="glide__bullet" data-glide-dir="=5"></button>
                        <button className="glide__bullet" data-glide-dir="=6"></button>
                        <button className="glide__bullet" data-glide-dir="=7"></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>)}
```

Answer (score 0):

NextJS works by hydrating prerendered HTML. NextJS generates HTML and js code on the server and then hands those to the browser. You are executing `document.querySelector` during the prerender (server), before the document is available (browser).

The trick is to use `document` only when it is guaranteed to be defined, like in a `useLayoutEffect` hook (which is only called after the component is loaded into the DOM):

pages/index.js

```
import Glide from "./components/Glide"

export default function Home() {
    useLayoutEffect(() => {
       // glide code here
    })

    return(
        <>
<div className="glide-container">
```

One way could be to write a hook called `useGlide` which executes `useLayoutEffect`.

Comment: I'm receiving this error message:

```Server Error
ReferenceError: useLayoutEffect is not defined

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Source
pages/index.js (19:2) @ useLayoutEffect

   17 | 
   18 | export default function Home() {
> 19 | useLayoutEffect(() => {
     |  ^
   20 |      let sliders = document.querySelectorAll('.glide');
   21 |   for (let i = 0; i < sliders.length; i++) {
   22 |       let glide = new Glide(sliders[i], {```

Comment: I'm still receiving an error after importing useLayoutEffect. The error is this one:

```Server Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useLayoutEffect')

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.```

Comment: I'm guessing you are importing it directly in glide.js? it needs to be used in a react component like any hook